How should I generate random forest regression model result to spatial distribution map?
I have been using the predict SOC distribution map in Python. For that reason, I am using Random Forest Regression in Python.
Firstly, I extracted all values from rasters then I used csv data to load model. My model is working fine and the statistical results are fine too.
However, I paused the process of generating model result to the spatial distribution map. Because I don't know how to generate that map?
So, I wondered and searched again. Some information said I had to use raster files into model in Python at the beginning. I tried that many times but it doesn't work it says there is some kind of different shape.
Therefore, How can I generate my model result to the spatial distribution map using rasters?
here is my model's code
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np 
import rasterio as rio
import statsmodels.api as sm
import geopandas as gpd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from rasterio.plot import show, show_hist
data = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
print(data)

X = data.drop('SOC', axis=1)  
y = data['SOC']
print("x:", X)
print("y:", y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

rf_regressor_train = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, 
random_state=706, oob_score=True)
r2_scores = []
rf_regressor_train.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_regressor_test = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, 
random_state=301, oob_score=True)
r2_scores = []
rf_regressor_test.fit(X_test, y_test)
rf_regressor_train.get_params()
rf_regressor_test.get_params()

# Access the OOB Score
oob_score = rf_regressor_train.oob_score_
print(f'Out-of-Bag Score: {oob_score}')

# Define hyperparameters to tune
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200, 1000, 2000],
    'max_depth': [None, 5, 10, 20],
    'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 7, 10, 15],
    'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4, 6, 8]
}

rfe_train = RFE(estimator=rf_regressor_train, 
n_features_to_select=17, step=1) 
rfe_tr = rfe_train.fit(X_train, y_train)
rfe_te = rfe_train.fit(X_test, y_test)
print(rfe_tr.fit)
selected_features_indices_train = rfe_tr.support_
selected_features_indices_test = rfe_te.support_
X_train_selected = X_train.iloc[:, selected_features_indices_train]
X_test_selected = X_test.iloc[:, selected_features_indices_test]

grid_search_train = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf_regressor_train, 
param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', 
n_jobs=-1)
grid_search_train.fit(X_train_selected, y_train)

best_params_train = grid_search_train.best_params_
print("Best Hyperparameters:", best_params_train)
best_rf_regressor_train = RandomForestRegressor(**best_params_train, 
random_state=42)
best_rf_regressor_train.fit(X_train_selected, y_train)
print(best_rf_regressor_train)

cv_scores_train = cross_val_score(best_rf_regressor_train, 
X_train_selected, y_train, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
print("Cross-Validation Scores:", cv_scores_train)
print("Average Cross-Validation Score:", np.mean(cv_scores_train))

selected_features = X_train.columns[rfe_tr.support_]
feature_ranking = rfe_train.ranking_
print("Selected Features:")
print(selected_features)
print("Feature Ranking:")
feature_importance = rfe_train.estimator_.feature_importances_
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
sns.barplot(x=feature_importance, y=selected_features, 
palette='mako')
plt.xlabel('Feature Importance')
plt.ylabel('Features')
plt.title('Feature Importance Evaluation')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('feature_importance.png')
plt.show()

y_pred = best_rf_regressor_train.predict(X_test_selected)
print(y_pred)
y_pred.size


r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("R^2 Score:", r2)
print("RMSE:", rmse)

data = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
print(data)

print("Feature Importance Scores:")
for feature, importance in zip(selected_features, 
feature_importance):
print(f"{feature}: {importance}")
print("Selected Features:", selected_features)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.scatter(y_test, y_pred, color='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot([-1, 1], [-1, 1], color='red', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('Actual')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Actual vs. Predicted Values')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

#Measuring accuracy on Training Data
print('Accuracy',100- (np.mean(np.abs((y_test - y_pred) / y_pred)) * 
100))

# Calculate feature importances (estimated scores)
feature_importances = best_rf_regressor_train.feature_importances_
print("Feature Importances:", feature_importances)


y_pred_rell = best_rf_regressor_train.predict(X)
print(y_pred_rell)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
